# Reshaping Numpy Arrays to a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

For a numpy array I have found that

```
x = numpy.array([]).reshape(0,4)
```

is fine and allows me to append (0,4) arrays to x without the array losing its structure (ie it dosnt just become a list of numbers). However, when I try

```
x = numpy.array([]).reshape(2,3)
```

it throws an error. Why is this?

Comment: Append `(2,3)` arrays along what axis? Use sample arrays to demonstrate what you have in mind?

Comment: Never mind about that just want to know why numpy.array([]).reshape(2,3) throws an error

Comment: `numpy.array([]).reshape(2,3)` throws error because `numpy.array([])` has zero elements, so you can't reshape that to `(2,3)` that expects total `6` elements.

Comment: So why does numpy.array([]).reshape(0,4) work

Comment: Are you trying to create an empty matrix of a certain size by doing reshape on an empty array? Why not use numpy.zeros or numpy.empty instead?

Comment: Because `.reshape(0,4)` expects zero elements `0*4 = 0`, while in `(2,3)`, it expects `2*3 = 6` elems.

Answer (score 1):

This out put will explain what it mean to reshape an array...

```
np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(2, 3)
```

Output -

```
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

So reshaping just means **reshaping an array**. reshape(0, 4) means convert the current array into a format with 0 rows and 4 columns intuitively. But 0 rows means no elements means so it works as your array is empty. Similarly (2, 3) means 2 rows and 3 columns which is 6 elements...

Answer (score 0):

`reshape` is not an 'append' function. It reshapes the array you give it to the dimensions you want.

`np.array([]).reshape(0,4)` works because you reshape a zero element array to a 0x4(=0 elements) array.
`np.reshape([]).reshape(2,3)` doesn't work because you're trying to reshape a zero element array to a 2x3(=6 elements) array.

To create an empty array use `np.zeros((2,3))` instead.

And in case you're wondering, numpy arrays can't be appended to. You'll have to work around by casting it as a `list`, appending what you want and the converting back to a numpy array. Preferably, you only create a numpy array when you don't mean to append data later.